# Scala ORM producing incompatible version build errors

Tags: scala, maven, squeryl, sorm

We have a working Scala application, using Scala 2.11.5.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>2.11.5</version>
</dependency>
```

When we introduce SORM, using the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.sorm-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>sorm</artifactId>
  <version>0.3.18</version>
</dependency>
```

the following two build errors occur:

```
scala-parser-combinators_2.12.0-M4-1.0.4.jar of xxx build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.12.0). 

scala-xml_2.12.0-M4-1.0.5.jar of xxx build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.12.0).
```

I have tried using older version of SORM, but similar problems occur. For instance, with version `0.3.8` :

```
slf4s_2.9.1-1.0.7.jar of xxx build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.9.1).
```

A similar problem exists when using `Squeryl` for the object relational mapping:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.squeryl</groupId>
  <artifactId>squeryl_2.9.3</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.5-7</version>
</dependency>
```

causes the following build error;

```
squeryl_2.9.3-0.9.5-7.jar of xxx build path is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.9.3).
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your Squeryl issue by referencing the correct Scala version in your POM.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.squeryl</groupId>
  <artifactId>squeryl_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.5-7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The project now builds - thanks. How does Squeryl compare with Sorm ?